# MySQL 'replace into select from' Alternative

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

I am currently using the following statement:
`REPLACE INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Col2 = 'Something' AND Col3 <> 'word'`

The issue with this is that *TableName* contains additional columns (i.e. *Col0*, *Col5*, *Col6*) that are not present in *AnotherTable* and whose data I do not want wiped.

I noticed that there is a statement called `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I am unsure how to merge this with the `SELECT * FROM` statement that I am using to copy specific data from another table.  How is this done, if possible?

Supplementary Python2.7 code is possible if necessary.

**Server version:** 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Col2 = 'Something' AND Col3 <> 'word' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=AnotherTable.Col1, Col2=AnotherTable.Col2, Col3=AnotherTable.Col3, Col4=AnotherTable.Col4`

Notice the ability to use fully qualified references via the format `Table.Column` as an alternative to a static/specified value.

As *danblack* reminds, the `REPLACE` functionality is taken over by the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that is introduced, which is dependant on `UNIQUE` indexes or `PRIMARY KEY`s.

Comment: Table.Column is not a variable - that's just the fully qualified reference to the column.

Comment: True, I was trying to think of the right term.  Thanks!

Comment: Note: what happens here will be largely controlled to what are `UNIQUE` indexes or `PRIMARY KEY` on `TableName` because those are the only things that can trigger the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` condition.